# How to reverse order of values but not keys in a python dictionnary?

Tags: python, dictionary, reverse

What is the best way to reverse order of values but not keys in a python dictionnary ?

```
dictionnary = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
inversed_values = dictionnary.reverseValues()
print(inversed_values)
```

This should print out `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert values to `list` then reverse them then create `dict` like below:

```
>>> dct = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
>>> dict(zip(dct.keys(),list(dct.values())[::-1]))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```